# Como conectar dois SELECT (combobox) em PHP e fazer Auto Preenchimento?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Gostaria de saber como conecto dois `select`. Como se tivesse uma categoria e uma sub-categoria, porém quero que apareça a sub-categoria quando eu clicar na categoria. Eu tenho duas tabelas no bd uma membro e outra exercício, quando eu escolher meu membro ele me liste todos os exercícios cadastrados para aquele membro.

Aqui, estou mostrando a minha "categoria"

```
            $database = new Database();
            $db = $database->getConnection();
            $exercicio = new exercicio($db);

            $membro = new membro($db);
            $stmt = $membro->read();

        echo "<select class='form-control' name='membro_corpo'>";
            echo "<option>Select Membro...</option>";

            while ($row_category = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                extract($row_category);
                echo "<option value='{$id_membro}'>{$nome_membro}</option>";
            }
    echo "</select>";
```

Agora quero que me mostre as "sub-categorias" quando eu clicar na categoria.

```
$stmt1 = $exercicio->read();

        echo "<select class='form-control' name='category_id'>";
            echo "<option>Select Exercicio...</option>";

            while ($row_exercicio = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                extract($row_exercicio);
                if($exercicio->id_membro_exer==$id_membro){
                    echo "<option value='$id_membro' selected";
                }else{
                    echo "<option value='$id_membro'";
                }
                echo "$nome_exer</option>";
            }

        echo "</select>";
```

Comment: É preciso usar ajax e javascript. Eu costumo usar jQuery em meus sites. Você usa jQuery ou apenas JS ?

Comment: Obrigado. Mas não sei programar ainda com Jquery e nem Ajax. De qualquer forma obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

A forma que fiz a baixo é um exemplo utilizando tecnologia ajax com jquery:

```
<div id="select_m">
 <label>Membros:</label>
  <select id="post_m" class='form-control' name='membro_corpo'>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="select_e">
  <label>Exercícios:</label>
    <select id="post_e" class='form-control' name='category_id'>
    </select>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
   var valor = 'all_members';
   carregarDados('ajax_select.php', valor, 'm','Selecionar membro');

    $('#select_e').hide();  

    $('#select_m select').on('change', function() {
      var valor = $(this).val();
      hideShowInputSubmit(valor, false, 'e');
      carregarDados('ajax_select.php', valor, 'e','Selecionar exercício');
    });

    $('#select_e select').on('change', function() {
      var valor = $(this).val();
      hideShowInputSubmit(valor, true, 'e');
    });

});

function hideShowInputSubmit(value, submeter, elementDisplay) {
     if (value == '') {
            $('#select_'+elementDisplay).hide();
         } else {
            $('#select_'+elementDisplay).show();
     }
     if (submeter) {
        //aqui você submete o valor final
        alert('Submeter form com valor: '+value);
     }
}

function carregarDados(url, valor_selecionado, id_select, default_title_value) {

    var data = {
             valor_selecionado:valor_selecionado,
             id_formulario:id_select
    };
    $.post(url,data,function(e) {
       var options = [];
       var default_option = '<option value="" selected>'
                            + default_title_value +
                            '</option>';

       var collection = jQuery.parseJSON(e);

       for (var i in collection) {
          options[i] = '<option value="'
                       + collection[i].id   + '">'
                       + collection[i].name + 
                       '</option>';
       }
       var opc = options.join("\n");
       var selects = [
               default_option, 
               opc
           ].join("");
       $('#post_'+id_select).html(selects);
    });    
}
</script>
```

No arquivo `ajax_select.php` em PHP você tem que retornar uma saída em JSON do `$_POST['valor_selecionado']` e `$_POST['id_formulario']` (`echo json_encode($seu_array)`).

Vamos supor que seja algo assim:

```
<?php
if($_POST) {

    if (isset($_POST['valor_selecionado'])) {
        $id = $_POST['valor_selecionado'];

        if (in_array($id, array('1','2', 'all_members'))
            && $_POST['id_formulario'] == 'm') {
          //membros
           $return = array(
              array('id'=>'1','name'=>'Luiz'),
              array('id'=>'2','name'=>'Fábio'),
            );
        }

        if (in_array($id, array('1','2','3'))
           && $_POST['id_formulario'] == 'e') {
           //exercícios
           $return = array(
              array('id'=>'1','name'=>'Exercício 1'),
              array('id'=>'2','name'=>'Exercício 2'),
              array('id'=>'3','name'=>'Exercício 3'),
            );
        }
    }
   echo json_encode($return);  
   exit();
}


?>
```

Se quiser testar, basta colocar o código em PHP antes do HTML e salvar um arquivo com nome "ajax_select.php" e executá-lo.

Comment: Obrigado pelo exemplo, mas não consegui aplicar em meu trabalho aqui.

Answer (score 1):

A forma mais prática seria utilizar ajax, crie uma função no jquery:

```
(function($){
    $.subcategoria = function(id) {
        if(id != '') {
            $('select#subcategoria').html('<option value="">Carregando...</option>');
            $.post('subcategorias.php', { categoria: id }, function(data) { $('select#subcategoria').html(data); });
        } else {
            $('select#subcategoria').html('<option>Select Exercicio...</option>');
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

No seu primeiro select você adiciona a chamada da função:

```
<select class="form-control" name="membro_corpo" onchange="$.subcategoria(this.value);">
```

No segundo select adicione o id `subcategoria` para usarmos na função

```
<select class="form-control" name="category_id" id="subcategoria">
```

Por fim, no seu arquivo php `subcategoria.php` (ou como desejar chamar) receba o id enviado via POST e liste as subcategorias relacionadas:

```
$categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
$stmt1 = $exercicio->read($categoria); // função que liste as subcategorias relacionadas
while($row_exercicio = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<option value=\"$id_membro\">$nome_exer</option>";
}
```

Você pode tanto imprimir no arquivo php as tags ja prontas para serem incluídas no campo select ou utilizar json e imprimir o objeto e montar as tags no jquery, essa é apenas uma das diversas formas.

Espero que ajude, abraço.

Comment: Obrigado, mas não consegui aplicar no meu trabalho, quando eu seleciono o membro ele não passa o parâmetro para o exercício.

Comment: você está importando o jquery para seu arquivo? exemplo: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Sim, coloquei essa linha de código. Talvez eu esteja fazendo alguma coisa de errado. Mas obrigado.

Comment: talvez essse artigo te ajude a iniciar o aprendizado em jquery: http://www.botecodigital.info/jquery/iniciando-com-jquery/